# .import csv is miscounting columns

Tags: linux, csv, import, sqlite

I have a table with 236 columns and I'm using the .import statement to populate the table.  I keep getting a "expected 236 columns, found 0" error.  The last 6 columns are empty and thinking that might be the issue, I inserted NULL in each field, but the data still won't import to the table though the error message does change slightly "expected 236 columns, found 237".

I have tried specifying the mode as csv, but that didn't help.

How can I get the .import function to count the columns correctly?

I am using sqlite3 on a Linux workstation.

Answer (score 0):

> I inserted NULL in each field, but the data still won't import to the table though the error message does change slightly "expected 236 columns, found 237".

Do you have any commas in your data? As in, not a comma that acts as a delimiter, but a comma in your row data?

It sounds like a comma in your data is adding an extra column when there shouldn't be one.

Comment: Yes, there are commas within some of the data, but those particular pieces of data are enclosed in quotes so I believe that comma is ignored.

Comment: The only way I see an extra column being in your data is if you have an extra comma somewhere. Perhaps try delimiting by something other than a comma?

Comment: I did try using the pipe as the deliminator, but I got the same result.

Comment: So, it appears the double quotes were causing the problem.  Once I removed them (and the comma in that field), I was able to import the record.  Is there a mode setting or something I can change so that SQLite will understand why the quotes are there?

I don't run into this error when creating an insert statement (where usually the data for each field is enclosed in double quotes).